# Fixed Sorted List / Data structure

Tags: c#, .net

I'm writing something to that logs the performance of various methods across objects. I want to find the top 10 slowest times. Hence I want something like a sorted list that's fixed, e.g in my case 10. So whenever I've got a new time, I just insert it and it orders it. It will be fixed, so after i've inserted the 5th time (assuming its limited to 5 for the example below) then the list won't grow, but it will just insert it into the list, and remove the smallest value.

E.g.

```
var topTen = new XXX<double>(5);

XXX.Insert(1);
XXX.Insert(3);
XXX.Insert(2);
XXX.Insert(6);
XXX.Insert(4);
XXX.Insert(5);

/*
topTen[0] is 6
topTen[1] is 5
topTen[2] is 4
topTen[3] is 3
topTen[4] is 2
*/
```

I was going to write something for it but I was just wondering if there was anything out there already in .net.

Comment: Not a built-in class. But you may find the `MyPriorityQueue` implementation [here](http://pastebin.com/NHDdrbYV) useful. It does exactly what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, you do something like this with a heap. For example:

```
var heap = new BinaryHeap<int>();

for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
{
    var time = GetTimeSomehow();
    if (heap.Count < 5)
    {
        heap.Insert(time);
    }
    else if (time > heap.Peek())
    {
        // the new value is larger than the smallest value on the heap.
        // remove the smallest value and add this one.
        heap.RemoveRoot();
        heap.Insert(time);
    }
}
```

That limits the size to 5, and when you're done you can get the top 5 in order:

```
while (heap.Count > 0)
{
    var time = heap.RemoveRoot();
    Console.WriteLine(time);
}
```

There is no heap data structure available in the .NET Framework. I published a simple one a while back. See [A Generic BinaryHeap Class](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=dotnet&seqNum=789).

Answer (score 0):

Try this (untested):

int listLength = 5;

```
List<int> list = new List<int>(listLength+1);

void VerifyTime(int time) {
  list[listLength] = time;
  var i = listLength;
  while (listLength>0  &&  list[listLength] < list[listLength-1])
    swap(list, listLength, listLength-1);
}

void swap (List<int> l, int a, int b) {
  var temp = l[a];
  l[a] = l[b];
  l[b] = temp;
}
```

For any small value of ListLength it should work just fine.